# Filter data in log file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have to analyze data from logfile that stored in "C:\read" directory, and output the data in the system. There is multiple log file, name "drivermonitor". The logfile contain device name, lotid, socket and wafer result. Each device have different socket quantity and three different wafer result. Filter data is start from "Bin2 Test Started" and wafer result for this logfile is B20000A1, B20000A2, B20000B2

Drivermonitor logfile example:

```
File c:\winapps\mbi\logs\ZLMH20N4FJ00N69HTTM045SP1REB1_DriverMonitor.log Created: 5/05/2018 02:30:35 PM Primary Diag: Bol1M5_DRV_V045.s19, Bol1M5_Dut_V045_1.s19, N/A, N/A

LOTID: ZLMH20N4FJ00N69HTTM045SP1REB1
Device Type: ENG-Bolero1M-4HR
Bin2 Test Started at 5/5/2018 7:37:22 PM
ZLMH20N4FJ00N69HTTM045SP1REB1,5/5/2018 7:37:22 PM,5/5/2018 7:37:37 PM,01119000090105,02140714160071,3,FACE00FF,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,FACE00FF,02083208,02083208,02083208,FACE00FF,02083208,02083208,FACE00FF,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,02083208,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,00300000,003FFCE8,0000875C,00300000,B20000A1,
ZLMH20N4FJ00N69HTTM045SP1REB1,5/5/2018 7:37:22 PM,5/5/2018 7:37:37 PM,01119000090105,02140714160071,3,FACE00FF,000B2532,000B2904,000B2832,000A180C,FACE00FF,000A2F18,000A3125,000A1F25,FACE00FF,000A1E20,000A210B,FACE00FF,000B2833,000A2D18,000A3425,000A2916,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,000A2E2D,000A0D2C,000A110D,000A0E0C,000A102C,000A120D,000A2725,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,000A252D,000A0B2C,000A150E,000A260C,000A2431,000A270C,000A222C,000A1725,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,2001A5A5,B20000A2,
ZLMH20N4FJ00N69HTTM045SP1REB1,5/5/2018 7:37:22 PM,5/5/2018 7:37:38 PM,01119000090105,02140714160071,3,FACE00FF,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,FACE00FF,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,FACE00FF,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,FACE00FF,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,5A5A5A5A,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,FACE00FF,0839C922,001E9808,000AAE61,00000004,B20000B2,
```

I already have the script but not working well:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objSTR, objEND, objTYP, objEXT, objKEY, objFILE, objKEY2
Dim Folder, SubFolder testfile,b,a,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,match,array,i,status,array2,array3,array4,array5,array6,d,mambastr,ten,n,eleven,twelve,k,nine
dim dtend,dtStart,bibid,driverid
dim objConnection,objRecordSet,ConnectionString,field,bin2
dim satu,dua,tiga,ti,empat,lima,enam,tujuh,lapan,sembilan,sepuluh,sebelas,duabelas,tigabelas,empatbelas,limabelas,enambelas
dim data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
objSTR = "C:\read" 'Folder To search through.
'objEND = "D:\SQLDEV\bin_miss_match\archive\" 'Folder To copy too.
objEXT = "log" 'do not include leading period '.' on the extension.
objTYP = "Text Document"
objKEY = "drivermonitor" 'keyword To search for along with the extension.
objKEY2 = "devicedata" 'keyword To search for along with the extension.

'outfile.writeline "lotid,date1,date2,bibcode,dontknow,slotno,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60"

OpenADOObjects2

For Each objFILE In objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR).Files
    b = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objfile.Path)
    Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(b, 1)
    Set one = New RegExp
    Set two = New RegExp
    Set three = New RegExpa
    Set four = New RegExp
    Set five = New RegExp
    Set six = New RegExp
    Set seven = New RegExp
    Set eight = New RegExp
    Set ten = New RegExp
    Set eleven = New RegExp
    Set twelve = New RegExp
    Set nine = New RegExp
    Set sepuluh = New RegExp
    Set sebelas = New RegExp
    Set duabelas = New RegExp

    Set satu = New RegExp
    Set dua = New RegExp
    Set tiga = New RegExp
    Set ti = New RegExp
    Set empat = New RegExp
    Set lima = New RegExp
    Set enam = New RegExp
    Set tujuh = New RegExp
    Set lapan = New RegExp
    Set sembilan = New RegExp
    Set tigabelas = New RegExp
    Set empatbelas = New RegExp

    Set limabelas = New RegExp
    Set enambelas = New RegExp

    Set data1 = New RegExp
    Set data2 = New RegExp
    Set data3 = New RegExp

    Set data4 = New RegExp
    Set data5 = New RegExp
    Set data6 = New RegExp
    bin2 = 0
    n = 0 'default calypso100&176&256 And mamba 324&416
    'one.Pattern = "[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s(AM|PM)\s-\s(FLS|fls|FSL|fsl|KLM|klm)_[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s(AM|PM),[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s(AM|PM),[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+:\s"

    ten.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Space2|SPACE2)"
    eleven.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Bolero|BOLERO)"
    twelve.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(((Panther|PANTHER)-CC3E)|((Quasar0|QUASAR0|Quasar2|QUASAR2)-CC3E))\b"
    sepuluh.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Calypso|CALYPSO)"
    sebelas.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s((Mamba|MAMBA)|4HR|6HR|8HR|12HR|CC3E)(-CC3E|)\b"
    duabelas.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(MPC551x|Mpc551X)"

    satu.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Batray|BATRAY)"
    dua.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Bonito|BONITO)"
    tiga.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Flipper|FLIPPER)-(144lds|144LDS)-(CC3|)\b"
    ti.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s((Flipper|FLIPPER)-(80lds|80LDS))|((Sailfish|SAILFISH)(-|)(80lds|80LDS))"
    empat.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(JELLYFISH|Jellyfish)"
    lima.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Kipper|KIPPER)-(80lds|80LDS)\b"
    enam.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Knifefish|KNIFEFISH)"
    tujuh.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Sailfish|SAILFISH)-(144lds|144LDS)"
    lapan.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s((SNAKEFISH|Snakefish)-3H-CC3)"
    sembilan.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(YellowFin|YELLOWFIN)"
    tigabelas.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Kipper|KIPPER)-(144lds|144LDS)"
    empatbelas.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(SpaceBridge|SPACEBRIDGE)"

    limabelas.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Marlin2|MARLIN2)"
    enambelas.Pattern = "\bDevice\sType:\s(Torpedo|TORPEDO)"

    one.Pattern = "[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s(AM|PM)\s-\s(FLS|fls|FSL|fsl|KLM|klm)"
    two.Pattern = "-"
    two.global = True
    three.Pattern = ",000000A1,$"
    four.Pattern = ",000000A2,$"
    five.Pattern = ",000000B2,$"
    '---------------Group 1-------------------------
    six.Pattern = ",B20000A1,$"
    seven.Pattern = ",B20000A2,$"
    eight.Pattern = ",B20000B2,$"
    '---------------Group 2-------------------------
    data1.Pattern = ",C1,$"
    data2.Pattern = ",C2,$"
    data3.Pattern = ",D2,$"
    '---------------Group 3-------------------------
    data4.Pattern = ",00A1,$"
    data5.Pattern = ",00C2,$"
    data6.Pattern = ",00D2,$"
    '---------------Group 4-------------------------
    data4.Pattern = ",00A1,$"
    data5.Pattern = ",00C2,$"
    data6.Pattern = ",00D2,$"

    nine.Pattern = "^Bin2.Test Started"

    Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
        a = testfile.ReadLine
        'MsgBox a

        If (ten.Test(a) = True) Or (empatbelas.Test(a) = True) Then    'space ,spacebridge
            n = 28
        End If

        If (eleven.Test(a) = True) Then    'bolero 100&144&176
            n = 55
        End If

        If (twelve.Test(a) = True) Or (duabelas.Test(a) = True) Then    'quasar0&2 And panther 144&257 And MPC
            n = 40
        End If

        If (sepuluh.Test(a) = True) Or (sebelas.Test(a) = True) Then    'calypso100&176&256 And mamba 324&416
            n = 36
        End If

        If (satu.Test(a) = True) Or (tiga.Test(a) = True)or (tujuh.Test(a) = True) Or (tigabelas.Test(a) = True)then 'batray 112 And flipper 144 And sailfish144 And kipper 144
            n = 60
        End If


        If (dua.Test(a) = True) Or (ti.Test(a) = True) Or (empat.Test(a) = True) Or (enam.Test(a) = True) Or (lapan.Test(a) = True) Or (sembilan.Test(a) = True) Or (lima.Test(a) = True) Then 'bonito And flipper 80 And jellyfish100 And knifefish64&80 And snakefish80&64 And yellowfin And kipper 80 And marlin And torpedo
            n = 72
        End If
        If (limabelas.Test(a)= True)OR (enambelas.Test(a) = True)then
            n = 702
        End If

        If (nine.Test(a) = True) Then
            bin2 = 1
        End If

        If (three.Test(a) = True) Then
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (four.Test(a) = True) Then
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (five.Test(a) = True) Then
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (six.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",B20000A1,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (seven.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",B20000A2,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (eight.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",B20000B2,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (data1.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",000000C1,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (data2.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",000000C2,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (data3.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",000000D2,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (data4.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",00A1,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (data5.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",00C2,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If

        If (data6.Test(a) = True And bin2 = 1) Then '",00D2,$"
            array = Split(a,",",-1,1)
            mamba
            'outfile.writeline mambastr
            additem
        End If
    Loop
Next

CloseADOObject

Sub mamba
    If (n = 28) Then '28 socket
        mambastr = ""
        'mambastr =array(6)&","&    array(7)&","&    array(8)&","&    array(9)&","&    array(10)&","&    array(11)&","&    array(12)&","&    array(13)&","&    array(14)&","&    array(15)&","&    array(16)&","&    array(17)&","&    array(18)&","&    array(19)&","&    array(20)&","&    array(21)&","&    array(22)&","&    array(23)&","&    array(24)&","&    array(25)&","&    array(26)&","&    array(27)&","&    array(28)&","&    array(29)&","&    array(30)&","&    array(31)&","&    array(32)& "," &array(33)
        For k=6 To 32
            mambastr = mambastr + array(k)&","
        Next
        mambastr = mambastr + array(33)
    End If

    If (n = 36) Then '36 socket
        mambastr = ""
        'mambastr =array(6)&","&    array(7)&","&    array(8)&","&    array(9)&","&    array(10)&","&    array(11)&","&    array(12)&","&    array(13)&","&    array(14)&","&    array(15)&","&    array(16)&","&    array(17)&","&    array(18)&","&    array(19)&","&    array(20)&","&    array(21)&","&    array(22)&","&    array(23)&","&    array(24)&","&    array(25)&","&    array(26)&","&    array(27)&","&    array(28)&","&    array(29)&","&    array(30)&","&    array(31)&","&    array(32)& "," &array(33)& ","&array(34)&","&    array(35)&","&    array(36)&","&    array(37)&","&    array(38)&","&    array(39)&","&    array(40)&","&    array(41)
        For k=6 To 40
            mambastr = mambastr + array(k)&","
        Next
        mambastr = mambastr + array(41)
    End If

    If (n = 55) Then '55 socket
        mambastr = ""
        'mambastr =array(6)&","&    array(7)&","&    array(8)&","&    array(9)&","&    array(10)&","&    array(11)&","&    array(12)&","&    array(13)&","&    array(14)&","&    array(15)&","&    array(16)&","&    array(17)&","&    array(18)&","&    array(19)&","&    array(20)&","&    array(21)&","&    array(22)&","&    array(23)&","&    array(24)&","&    array(25)&","&    array(26)&","&    array(27)&","&    array(28)&","&    array(29)&","&    array(30)&","&    array(31)&","&    array(32)& "," &array(33)& ","&array(34)&","&    array(35)&","&    array(36)&","&    array(37)&","&    array(38)&","&    array(39)&","&    array(40)&","&    array(41) &","&    array(42) &","&    array(43)&","&    array(44)&","&    array(45)&","&    array(46)&","&    array(47)&","&    array(48)&","&    array(49)&","&    array(50) &","&    array(51)&","&    array(52)&","&    array(53)&","&    array(54)&","&    array(55)&","&    array(56)&","&    array(57)&","&    array(58)&","&    array(59)&","&    array(60)
        For k=6 To 59
            mambastr = mambastr + array(k)&","
        Next
        mambastr = mambastr + array(60)
    End If

    If (n = 40) Then '40 socket
        mambastr = ""
        'mambastr =array(6)&","&    array(7)&","&    array(8)&","&    array(9)&","&    array(10)&","&    array(11)&","&    array(12)&","&    array(13)&","&    array(14)&","&    array(15)&","&    array(16)&","&    array(17)&","&    array(18)&","&    array(19)&","&    array(20)&","&    array(21)&","&    array(22)&","&    array(23)&","&    array(24)&","&    array(25)&","&    array(26)&","&    array(27)&","&    array(28)&","&    array(29)&","&    array(30)&","&    array(31)&","&    array(32)& "," &array(33)& ","&array(34)&","&    array(35)&","&    array(36)&","&    array(37)&","&    array(38)&","&    array(39)&","&    array(40)&","&    array(41) &","&    array(42) &","&    array(43)&","&    array(44)&","&    array(45)
        For k=6 To 44
            mambastr = mambastr + array(k)&","
        Next
        mambastr = mambastr + array(45)
    End If

    If (n = 60) Then 
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 To 64
            mambastr = mambastr + array(k)&","
        Next
        mambastr = mambastr + array(65)
    End If

    If (n = 72) Then 
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 To 76
            mambastr = mambastr + array(k)&","
        Next
        mambastr = mambastr + array(77)
    End If

    If (n = 702) Then 
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 To 76
            mambastr = mambastr + array(k)&","
        Next
        mambastr = mambastr + array(77)
    End If
End Sub

Sub OpenADOObjects2
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11; Server=192.168.30.11; Database=d.Test2; UID=sa; Pwd=Win32API"
    objConnection.Open
    Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    objRecordSet.Open "Select * from tb.Test", objConnection, 1, 3
End Sub

Sub CloseADOObject
    objRecordSet.Close
    objConnection.Close
End Sub

Sub additem
    objRecordSet.AddNew
    objRecordSet("data")= a
    objRecordSet("sockstr")= mambastr
    objRecordSet.Update
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:** reconstructed the code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'dim outfile: Set outfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\faeq\Desktop\BIN2 Missmatch\output\testdata.log",2,true)
'dim outfolder : Set outfolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\faeq\Desktop\Dest ")
Dim objSTR, objEND, objTYP, objEXT, objKEY, objFILE, objKEY2
Dim  testfile,b,a,dateTime,dash,array,mambastr,sock,k,nine
dim  devnames,  line, Split
dim objConnection,objRecordSet,ConnectionString,bin2, m
dim waf1,waf2,waf3,waf4, waf5, waf6, waf7, waf8, waf9, waf10, waf11, waf12

objSTR = "C:\read" 'Folder to search through.
'objEND = "D:\SQLDEV\bin_miss_match\archive\" 'Folder to copy too.
objEXT = "log" 'do not include leading period '.' on the extension.
objTYP = "Text Document"
objKEY = "drivermonitor" 'keyword to search for along with the extension.
objKEY2 = "devicedata" 'keyword to search for along with the extension.

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OpenADOObjects2

For Each objFILE in objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR).Files
    Set testfile = objFSO.OpenAsTextStream
    line = ""
    Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
        line= testfile.ReadLine

        set Split =new regexp
        set dateTime =new regexp
        set dash =new regexp
        set a =new regexp
        Set m = New regExp
        set nine = new regexp
        set line = new regexp
        Set re2 = New RegExp
        Set re = New regExp
        Set waf1 = New regExp
        Set waf2 = New regExp
        Set waf3 = New regExp
        Set waf4 = New regExp
        Set waf5 = New regExp
        Set waf6 = New regExp
        Set waf7 = New regExp
        Set waf8 = New regExp
        Set waf9 = New regExp
        Set waf10 = New regExp
        Set waf11 = New regExp
        Set waf12 = New regExp
        re.Pattern = "^Device\sType:\s(.*)"
        For Each m In re.Execute(line)
            devnames = m.Submatches(24)
        Next

        re2.Pattern = "^[^-]*-|-[^-]*$"
        re2.Global  = True
        devnames = re2.Replace(devnames, "")

        Set devnames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        devnames.Add "Bolero", True
        devnames.Add "Habanero", True
        devnames.Add "Spacebridge", True
        devnames.Add "Marlin", True
        devnames.Add "Torpedo", True
        devnames.Add "Calypso", True
        devnames.Add "Mamba", True
        devnames.Add "Mpc", True
        devnames.Add "Panther", True
        devnames.Add "Quasar", True
        devnames.Add "Swordfish", True
        devnames.Add "Batray", True
        devnames.Add "Bonito", True
        devnames.Add "Flipper", True
        devnames.Add "Jelly", True
        devnames.Add "Kipper", True
        devnames.Add "Knifefish", True
        devnames.Add "Sailfish", True
        devnames.Add "Snakefish", True
        devnames.Add "Yellowfin", True
        devnames.Add "Agave", True
        devnames.Add "Grusonia", True
        devnames.Add "Oroya", True

        For Each m In re.Execute(line)
            devnames = m.Submatches(24)
        Next

        bin2 = 0
        sock = 0

        dateTime.pattern = "[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s(AM|PM)\s-\s(FLS|fls|FSL|fsl|KLM|klm)"
        dash.pattern = "-"
        dash.global = True
        waf1.pattern = ",000000A1,$"
        waf2.pattern = ",000000A2,$"
        waf3.pattern = ",000000B2,$"
        '---------------Group 1-------------------------
        waf4.pattern = ",B20000A1,$"
        waf5.pattern = ",B20000A2,$"
        waf6.pattern = ",B20000B2,$"
        '---------------Group 2-------------------------
        waf7.pattern = ",000000C1,$"
        waf8.pattern = ",000000C2,$"
        waf9.pattern = ",000000D2,$"
        '---------------Group 3-------------------------
        waf10.pattern = ",00A1,$"
        waf11.pattern = ",00C2,$"
        waf12.pattern = ",00D2,$"

        If devnames.Exists("Bolero") or devnames.Exists("Mpc")  Then
            sock = 55
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Habanero") Then
            sock = 20
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Marlin") or devnames.Exists("Torpedo") or devnames.Exists("Bonito") or devnames.Exists("Flipper") or devnames.Exists("Jelly") or devnames.Exists("Kipper") or devnames.Exists("Knifefish") or devnames.Exists("Sailfish") or devnames.Exists("Snakefish") or devnames.Exists("Yellowfin")Then
            sock = 72
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Calypso") Then
            sock = 36
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Mamba") or devnames.Exists("Spacebridge") Then
            sock = 28
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Panther") or devnames.Exists("Quasar") Then
            sock = 40
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Swordfish") or devnames.Exists("Batray")  Then
            sock = 60
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Agave") Then
            sock = 128
        End If
        If devnames.Exists("Grusonia") or devnames.Exists("Oroya") Then
            sock = 120
        End If

        Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
            a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")

            if (nine.test(a) = true) then
                bin2 = 1
            end if

            if (waf1.test(a) =true) then
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf2.test(a) =true) then
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf3.test(a) = true) then
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf4.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",B20000A1,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf5.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",B20000A2,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf6.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",B20000B2,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf7.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",000000C1,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf8.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",000000C2,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf9.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",000000D2,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf10.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",00A1,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf11.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",00C2,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if

            if (waf12.test(a) =true and bin2 = 1) then '",00D2,$"
                a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
                mamba
                'outfile.writeline mambastr
                additem
            end if
        loop
        v = a(UBound(a)-1)
    loop
next

CloseADOObject

Sub mamba
    if (sock = 28) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 32
            mambastr= mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(33)
    end if

    if (sock = 36) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 40
            mambastr= mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(41)
    end if

    if (sock = 55) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 59
            mambastr=mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(60)
    end if

    if (sock = 40) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 44
            mambastr= mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(45)
    end if

    if (sock = 60) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 64
            mambastr=mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(65)
    end if

    if (sock = 72) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 76
            mambastr=mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(77)
    end if
    if (sock = 20) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 24
            mambastr=mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(25)
    end if
    if (sock = 128) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 132
            mambastr=mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(133)
    end if
    if (sock = 120) then
        mambastr = ""
        For k=6 to 124
            mambastr=mambastr + a(k)&","
        next
        mambastr = mambastr + a(125)
    end if
end sub
testfile.Close

sub OpenADOObjects2
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    objConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11; Server=192.168.30.11; Database=dbtest2; UID=sa; Pwd=Win32API"
    objConnection.Open
    set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    objRecordSet.Open "Select * from tbltest",objConnection,1,3

end sub

sub CloseADOObject
    objRecordSet.Close
    objConnection.Close
end sub

sub additem
    objRecordSet.AddNew
    objRecordSet("data")= a
    objRecordSet("sockstr")= mambastr
    objRecordSet.Update
end sub
```

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem you're facing.

Comment: certain device not working well with this code. @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: "Not working well" is not a problem description. What is the behavior you expect? What is the behavior you observe? We're not sitting in front of your computer.

Comment: That's a lot of `RegExp` objects...why so many? You could have handled the various parameters in a loop and only needed one `RegExp` object.

Comment: Thats the name of the devices and wafer results @Lankymart

Answer (score 1):

This may not actually answer your question (because it's not entirely clear to me what your question is in the first place), but should offer some general guidelines for improving your code.

Usually when processing CSV-style files the best approach is to read the file line by line, split each line, then base the further processing on the values of specific fields in the resulting array.

```
For Each f In objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR).Files
    Set testfile = f.OpenAsTextStream
    Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
        a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
        '...
        'further processing occurs here
        '...
    Loop
    testfile.Close
Next
```

For opening a file it's not necessary to get the full path from a `File` object first, then call `OpenTextFile` with that path. You can directly open a text file from the `File` object with the object's `OpenAsTextStream` method.

If you have a file format that prepends CSV-style data with a differently formatted header I'd recommend processing that header first in a separate loop:

```
For Each f In objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR).Files
    Set testfile = f.OpenAsTextStream
    line = ""
    Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream Or InStr(line, "Test Started at") > 0
        line = testfile.ReadLine
        '...
        'process headers here
        '...
    Loop
    Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
        a = Split(testfile.ReadLine, ",")
        '...
        'process CSV data here
        '...
    Loop
    testfile.Close
Next
```

Extract the device type from the header section with a single regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^Device\sType:\s(.*)"
For Each m In re.Execute(line)
    devtype = m.Submatches(0)
Next
```

Given your example the variable `devtype` will then contain the value "ENG-Bolero1M-4HR". You can remove unwanted prefixes and/or suffixes from that string e.g. like this:

```
Set re2 = New RegExp
re2.Pattern = "^[^-]*-|-[^-]*$"
re2.Global  = True
devtype = re2.Replace(devtype, "")
```

The above will change the string "ENG-Bolero1M-4HR" to "Bolero1M".

Use a dictionary for mapping the extracted strings to other values:

```
Set devtypes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
devtypes.Add "Bolero1M", 55
...

nval = devtypes(devtype)
```

or for basing decisions on the presence of a value:

```
Set devtypes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
devtypes.Add "Bolero1M", True
...

If devtypes.Exists(devtype) Then
    ...
End If
```

In the CSV section you extract the value of the second-last field like this:

```
v = a(UBound(a)-1)
```

Also, if you find yourself doing the same (or very similar) operations repeatedly in your code, you should consider wrapping those operations in a procedure or function. And use descriptive names for procedure/function/variable names.

Comment: If devnames.Exists(devname), is this correct or the "s" is missing?If devnames.Exists(devnames)? I am trying using your code guidline

Comment: @sapkoklu `devnames.Exists(devname)` would return True if the value of the *variable* `devname` is present as a key in the *dictionary* `devnames`, and False if such a key is missing.

Comment: Probably. But I'd suggest you start with the points I outlined in my answer.

Comment: I already reconstruct the code, but its not working @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Can you check my code, whats wrong with it, I am new to this vbscript @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: I'm not going to debug 300 LoC for you, particularly not with a problem description like "it's not working". I already asked you to reduce your code to a [mcve]. More specifically, break your problem down into specific tasks. Get each individual task working. Then combine the code. Like, process header -> process CSV section -> process one file -> process multiple files.

Comment: Feel your pain @AnsgarWiechers. Personally, I wouldn’t have answered as it’s clear they just want a glorified debugger.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The problem with this code is, let say i want to run bolero device data, then,  i need to block comment on other device first to run the data, if not it will pop up no data found. Please help me......

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i need to add new device in this script, and already done it, but the problem is it pop up message "no data found". So can you help me...